# Opening a big PDF file on an ipad without downloading it first

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf, streaming, pdf-generation

Let's say I have a 400MB PDF, on a web server, and I want an ipad user to be able to open it and to start looking at it as soon as possible, without downloading the file entirely first. What are the options?

- Is Safari able to stream a large PDF like this? Can it start showing the first pages while the file is still downloading?
- Is there a way to build a native app to achieve this? If so, should the PDF be "spitted" first on the server? How?

Any tips on how to open a large PDF, in a friendly way and on an ipad, would be appreciated. Bonus points if the index of the PDF is accessible!

Comment: this might sound stupid, but you could have the server break up the pdf into separate pdf pages, and then on the front end you can download them 1 at a time, well first download how many pages there are, and then download the first one, when it's done download the second, and on the front end display the first page and every few seconds the user would see a new page enter.

Comment: '*Linearized*', or '*optimized for fast web view*' PDF was introduced exactly for this reason - "to show first page while the file is still downloading", but it seems that only Adobe software (Reader and browser plugins) takes advantage of this feature.

Comment: Thank you both for your help! But could you give more details about each solution? For example, how would you automatically split a pdf file page by page and still be able to show the table of content to the user so he can target a particular page (let say there are 5000 pages)? For linearized PDFs, is there documentation listing clients on the ipad supporting the feature? I see Adobe Reader for ipad doesn't run on ipad 1, is there an alternative? Also, would the TOC be accessible as soon as the file starts downloading?

Comment: As for "listing clients" -- like I said, only Reader does it. I've seen claims, that though linearized file format may be documented well enough (please google and read official (ISO, too) documentation), details, on what client requests, are not documented too thoroughly (hm-m...). Also, about "TOC be accessible as soon as the file starts downloading", -- regardless of what it is written about linearization, e.g. fast access to the 1st page, and then 2nd, and to the links, etc., -- the PDF spec only writes about **first page display ASAP, and that's all**, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @electrotype did u find the solution, i need to implement the same. If u know please help me. Thanks alot.

Comment: Sorry posha, I have nothing interesting to add on the subject!

Answer (score 1):

To clear things out:

- *Linearized* PDF has its order of objects reordered, so that all required data to display page are in front of the others. You can read more details in [PDF specification](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) in Annex F (page 683)

In case You haven't found application, that supports *Linearized* PDF, the best solution from my perspective would be rendering pages at the server side and create custom protocol to transfer only a single page with the table of contents.

Unless You want to create custom PDF viewer with *Linearized* PDF, You just create small portable "**page viewer**", which can quickly show the table of contents and then ask server for exact page number.

Example Server Interface:

```
class Pages
{
    string title;
    int number;
}

Stream GetDocumentPage(Page n);
List<Page> GetDocumentPages();
```

For this, one can use open-source solutions (such as [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/)) to parse pdf file and render the required page. Then send the binary data over Your custom protocol and display page at Your small portable "**page viewer**".

This solution does not require downloading whole document as it can cause significant network traffic.

Hope this helps.